# Confusion trying to turn rows into columns using SQL in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new to bigquery and I am trying to write an sql query to achieve something specific. below is a sample data

```
|primary_type| year|
|robery      | 2001|
|robery      | 2001|
|robery      | 2002|
|BATTERY     | 2001|
|BATTERY     | 2001|
|BATTERY     | 2002|
```

the below query is able to generate this

```
select primary_type,
    year,
   count(*) as number_of_crime 
FROM
`bigquery-public-data`
group by primary_type, year
order by year asc;

|primary_type| year|number_of_crime|
|robery      | 2001| 2             |
|robery      | 2002| 1             |
|BATTERY     | 2001| 2             |
|BATTERY     | 2002| 1             |
```

But the objective is to be able to create this and im not sure how to go about it

```
|year|robery|BATTERY|
|2001|2     |2      |
|2002|1     |1      |
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? The results you already get are in the preferred format for SQL. If it's for further data manipulation or processing, don't do this. If it's for presentation purposes, do this in your presentation layer, not your database.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
execute immediate format('''
select * from your_table
pivot (count(*) for primary_type in (%s))
''', (select "'" || string_agg(distinct primary_type, "','") || "'" from your_table))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]